# How to call limit post of author on author page (wordpress)

Tags: php, wordpress

I want to show author's limited `post` `titles` on the author page.
I'm using the code outside the `wordpress loop` to show limited post of author and the code is  `<?php query_posts('posts_per_page=20'); ?>` . but its showing recent post and i want only posts from author.

How to do this, anybody have idea?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Sample Code

```
<?php   

$the_query = new WP_Query(array('posts_per_page'=>20,'author'=>$put_author_id_here) );

while ( $the_query->have_posts() ) : the_post();

/* display the post as you do in loop*/

endwhile;

wp_reset_postdata();

?>
```

Comment: If there is more than one author, how it will be work.

Comment: only single author can make a post and so ID of author will be only a single value

Comment: just make a function which takes author id as a parameter to fetch posts of that author and use it any where just passing author ID

Answer (score 0):

use

```
query_posts('posts_per_page=20&author=$ID');
```

or use

```
query_posts('posts_per_page=20&author_name="admin"');
```

Comment: It is showing up recent post only and i want post from author :(

Comment: use what i told or use wp_query instead